# convert cstring to python string object

Tags: python, string, char, python-c-api

I have a function wrapper for c and python. This wrapper will receive 2 string arguments and convert these two into a tuple and pass it to python script. fileName and className are the c string arguments. pFunc is the python function name.

```
PyObject *pArgs, *pValue,*pFunc;
pValue = PyString_FromString(fileName);
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
pValue = PyString_FromString(className);
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
```

the error was cannot convert QString to const char*

i have tried the PyUnicode_FromString API, but still doesnt work, and gave the same error

the inputs are strings and i just want to make the PyObject_CallObject work, regardless of what type of pValue is (preferably strings too).... how do i do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the error was cannot convert QString to const char*

So your strings `fileName` and `className` are `QString` objects, not C strings (`const char*`)?  You have to convert the data first, for example using [`QString::toAscii()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#toAscii):

```
pValue = PyString_FromString(fileName.toAscii().data());
```